# Permission issue running Java

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to access JSON on remote server. The code works on a local replica of the database but on the server there is a "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception" error. I have lotusscript agents doing similar things so I am thinking it is a problem with java permissions on the server.

As far as I can tell I have all permissions on the server to run the code. I've tried putting the code in to Javascript and a Java managed bean so don't think it is an issue with the code.

The server is running 11.0.1FP1 (I've read there may be issues with pol files in 11)

Any help or hints would be greatly received

```
public String getJSON(String url)
{
    String returnCode = url;
     try {
         String jsonTxt = null;
         URL myURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
        if (myURLConnection.getResponseCode() < 400) {
            returnCode = "Connection made";
        } else {
               /* error from server */
            jsonTxt = "Can not access remote server";
            returnCode = "Connection not made";
            }
        myURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return returnCode;

     
}
```

Comment: I just tested the code on a 11.0.1FP1 and didn't have any problems.
Do you have the StackTrace and does the method return the initial returnCode value?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this line throwing the error
myURLConnection.getResponseCode()
this are from the server log - 
 HTTP JVM: CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml 
11/11/2020 08:46:47 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml 
11/11/2020 08:46:48 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /interiors/admin.nsf/Resourcing.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml

Comment: Download and install the Logreader.nsf database. It'll give you a lot more info quite often.

Comment: Does not work! Maybe same issue......[006258:000419-00007F47F63BF700] 12/11/2020 09:56:31 AM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in /Partitions/domino-146.prism-it.co.uk/domino/workspace/logs

Comment: SOLVE (I think!) - I Added my ID to security fields in Server doc (I was in group previously)